How to skip VCR body validation for specific files using RSpec?
In the company I work at, we are facing the following issue: initially we set our RSpec vcr config not to match request bodies. Currently we're trying to implement request body match, but we're left with a backlog of tests that would have to be adjusted to pass, and we want a quick way to start matching body requests for the new test files, without needing to fix all the previous ones.
I made it work with the following strategy:

Listed all the test files that did not pass as I turned on VCR body matching
Saved the file names to an array called SKIP_VCR_BODY_MATCHER in a ruby file
Implemented the following change to the spec_helper.rb file:

config.around do |example|
    test_file = example.metadata[:rerun_file_path]
    match_requests_on = SKIP_VCR_BODY_MATCHER.include?(test_file) ? [:method, :uri] : [:method, :uri, :body]
    VCR.configure do |c|
      c.default_cassette_options.merge!(match_requests_on:)
    end
    example.run
  end

The solution described above is working, but it feels like there should be a more straightforward way to tackle it. So I'd like to ask if anyone there has come accross a similar issue and did it differently. I appreciate the help!
